# New top bar menus need chevron

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

The new top bar needs an arrow/chevron/marker indicating at the items that are the menus. Its confusing that some items open a menu, while others are full links.

The review queue is not a menu, but a full link - mistake on my part on how confusing this is.

[image]

Comment: Actually, the second from the right isn't a menu either. Its a link too!

Comment: yep its very confusing.

Comment: The review queue will likely be a dropdown in a near future iteration.

Comment: I agree that the menus should *all* behave like menus. I don't have any issue with the profile link being different. Perhaps a *separator* between the menus and the profile is something to think about.

Answer (score -6):

I think it is fine the way it is. It did not confuse me at all and I would rather not have the extra clutter of meaningless chevrons that are just as likely to confuse people.

Comment: If at least the grouping made sense (link, dropdown, dropdown, link, dropdown ಠ_ಠ).

Comment: [So make the review button a dropdown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343341/new-top-bar-menus-need-chevron/343343?noredirect=1#comment445028_343341)